# ¿Como ejecutar una function() cuando se da click en un botón? (AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Este es mi codigo del index.php:
Lo que quiero es que al pulsar el botón de id #login se ejecute la funcion del script, la cual tiene dentro una funcion con AJAX, es un sistema de login sencillo para pruebas
Lo que no entiendo es porque cuando presiono en el boton, ni siquiera se coloca el texto del beforeSend, que es "Conectando..."
¿La Sintaxis no es correcta?
Es parte de mi primera pagina Web para un cliente real

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Pruebas con formularios AJAX </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form method="POST">
          <br> <br>
          <h1><p class="text-center"> Login </p></h1>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user">Usuario o Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success">
          </div>
          <span id="result"></span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login").click(function(){
        var user = ('#user').val();
        var pass = ('#pass').val();
        if($.trim(user).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0){
          $.ajax({
            url:"./action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user:user, pass:pass},
            cache:"false",
            beforeSend:function(){
              $('#login').val("Conectando...");
            },
            success:function(){
              if(data="1"){
                $(location).attr('href', './indexUser.php');
              } else {
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Las credenciales son erroneas.</div>");
              }
            }
          });
        };
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Scripts of Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te falta el **$** en ('#user').val(); y ('#pass').val();

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que **estás incluyendo la librería de jQuery al final**. Entonces, usas código de jQuery antes de que esta librería sea cargada.

Para no liarnos demasiado, veamos una prueba simple:

Este código funciona, porque la librería jQuery se carga al principio, en el `head`, de modo que cuando el DOM se carga, antes del código jQuery se incluye la librería.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Pruebas con formularios AJAX </title>

  <!-- Aquí cargamos la librería antes que nada -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<button id="login">Pulse aquí</button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login").click(function(){
      alert("Funciona");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la estructura que tienes, que no funciona, porque la librería se carga al final del `body`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Pruebas con formularios AJAX </title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="login">Pulse aquí</button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#login").click(function(){
      alert("NO Funciona");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Cuando viene a cargarse jQuery, ya has incluido arriba código jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Si revisas la consola para este caso, verás los mensajes de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos ellos ocurren porque se usa código jQuery sin haber cargado la librería.

Lo mismo podría estar ocurriendo con las otras librerías que incluyes al final del `body`. Si usas algo relativo a ellas en el `body`, esas librerías deben incluirse arriba, en el `head`.

Debes evitar también la **duplicidad de librerías**, por ejemplo, la librería `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css` la incluyes dos veces, al principio y al final.

Corrigiendo eso, debería funcionar.